# Trouble parsing out shapefile by market using geopandas package

Tags: python, geopandas

im trying to follow documentation from https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html to try to read subsets of a massive shapefile.

this is the code they give as an example to read in a subset of just data in Africa:

```
gdf_mask = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")
)
gdf = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"),
    mask=gdf_mask[gdf_mask.continent=="Africa"],
)
```

Now here is the code i used for my case:

```
newdf_mask = geopandas.read_file('C:\\Users\\path\\to\\file.zip')
newdf = geopandas.read_file('C:\\Users\\path\\to\\file.zip', mask=newdf_mask[newdf_mask.RMName = "Tampa/St. Petersburg"],)
```

I received an invalid syntax error. I also tried it without that trailing comma which seems out of place but they have it in their example.

as you can see from my code, I want to read a subset of the shapefile where the RMName = "Tampa/St. Petersburg".

Is this the best way to do it or is there a better or easier way?

Answer (score 0):

as documentation said :

> You can also load ZIP files that contain your data:
> zipfile = "zip:///Users/name/Downloads/cb_2017_us_state_500k.zip"
> states = geopandas.read_file(zipfile)

and you dont specified "zip:///" in your code.

```
newdf_mask = geopandas.read_file('C:\\Users\\path\\to\\file.zip')
```

try that and if you recieve error, post error message

Comment: the first line zipfile = "zip:///Users/name/Downloads/cb_2017_us_state_500k.zip"  throws this error  
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 6-7: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 0):

- you are trying to read **zip** file, where as you should be reading **shape** files
- code below better shows this - downloads zip files, unzips them then reads shape files

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path
import urllib
from zipfile import ZipFile
import geopandas as gpd

# fmt: off
url = ["https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip",
       "https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_populated_places.zip"]

# fmt: on

for url in url:
    f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
    if not f.exists():
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
        with open(f, "wb") as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

# NB reading shape file, not zip file
gdf_mask = gpd.read_file(list(Path.cwd().glob("ne_110m*/*countries*.shp"))[0])

gdf = gpd.read_file(
    list(Path.cwd().glob("ne_110m*/*populated*.shp"))[0],
    mask=gdf_mask.loc[gdf_mask["CONTINENT"].eq("Africa")],
)

# visualize....
m = gdf_mask.loc[
    gdf_mask["CONTINENT"].eq("Africa"), ["CONTINENT", "geometry"]
].explore()
gdf.loc[:, ["NAME", "geometry"]].explore(m=m, color="red")
```

Comment: hm, I'm not sure if this will work because the system I'm trying to upload to requires the suite of accompany files to the shapefile so if this code is only parsing the .shp file and not the others.

Comment: the point is the other files are in same directory so are used

Comment: `[(f.parent.stem,f.name) for f in Path.cwd().glob("ne_110m*/*populated*.*")]` [('ne_110m_populated_places', 'ne_110m_populated_places.shx'),
 ('ne_110m_populated_places', 'ne_110m_populated_places.cpg'),
 ('ne_110m_populated_places', 'ne_110m_populated_places.shp'),
 ('ne_110m_populated_places', 'ne_110m_populated_places.dbf'),
 ('ne_110m_populated_places', 'ne_110m_populated_places.README.html'),
 ('ne_110m_populated_places', 'ne_110m_populated_places.prj'),
 ('ne_110m_populated_places', 'ne_110m_populated_places.VERSION.txt')]